# Append the text to a div, not the html

Tags: jquery

I have this, and it works:

```
local.Source = $('article.hero-unit').html();
$('#Source').text(local.Source);
```

But what I'd like to do is this:

```
local.Source = $('article.hero-unit').html();
$('fieldset').append(local.Source);
```

The problem is that the append method appends the html and doesn't escape the < symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
local.Source = $('article.hero-unit').html();
var $fieldset = $('fieldset');
$fieldset.text($fieldset.text()+local.Source);
```

Calling `.text()` without parameters grabs the text already in the element. All this does is add the html of `local.Source` to it

Comment: Well, my problem is I lose my <legend>.

Comment: @Phillip I'm not sure I understand your problem, I'm assuming your legend tag is nested in your fieldset which would mean my code should work. Would you mind creating a fiddle (codepen.io or jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com ) illustrating the problem with this code or at least saying what the expected input and output are?

Comment: @Phillip What did you end up doing? What was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would put that text into a `<span>` element:

```
$('<span>', {
    text: local.Source
}).appendTo('fieldset');
```

Comment: Hi, I'm wondering why you think this is a better solution than the one I proposed? (by the way, you're an SO beast :) great work!)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: It's just another way of doing it. Wrapper elements let you style the text chunks and make it easier to remove them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick:

```
local.Source = $('article.hero-unit').html();
local.Legend = $('fieldset legend').text();
$('fieldset').text(local.Source);
$('fieldset').prepend('<legend>' + local.Legend + '</legend>');
```